# Converting string to hasthtable gives a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashtable, type-conversion

I'm writing a code that reads a file which is in json and convert it do hashtable.

However I'm having a `NullPointerException` when i try to convert String to hashtable.

```
readBackInfo = gson.fromJson(readjsonString, fileInfoType);
```

Here's the code I'm implementing

```
public void readSyncFile(){
    String readjsonString = null;
    readBackInfo = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(_dirName+"/."+_dirName);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            if(readjsonString==null){
                readjsonString = strLine;
            } else {
                readjsonString = readjsonString + "\n" + strLine;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        //System.out.println(readjsonString);

        Type fileInfoType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>>() {}.getType();

        System.out.println(allFiles.isEmpty());

        //getting a NullPointerException from the line below!
        readBackInfo = gson.fromJson(readjsonString, fileInfoType);

        sFileInToHashtable();
        //readjsonString = gson.toJson(readBackInfo);
        //System.out.println(readjsonString);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: When asking a question about getting an exception, it is always a good idea to include the stack-trace in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is setting `readjsonString` between:

```
String readjsonString = null;
```

and:

```
if(readjsonString.isEmpty()){
```

So the first exception you're catching is expected, and what you are doing is **not** good practice at all. If `readjsonString` being null is expected (as it is here), check for that.

```
if (readjsonString == null) {
  readjsonString = strLine;
} else {
  ...
}
```

It would be even better if you used [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) - that's what it's for.

The second NPE will happen exactly *there* only if `gson` is null. That variable is not defined or set in what you posted, so can't know if this is possible or not.

If the exception is occurring *inside* the `fromJson` method call, it could be because you read no input at all and `readjsonString` would thus still be null. So switch to a StringBuilder and stop using exceptions for normal flow control and you should be ok.

If this doesn't solve your problems, you'll need to post the stack trace.

Comment: I forgot to add `gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();`!, thanx^^ its solved now

Comment: You should _really_ consider the advice I and others gave. Using exceptions for normal flow control is **not** good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes... the first time you access `readJsonString` is after you've only assigned it a value of `null`. Effectively:

```
String readjsonString = null;

...
if(readjsonString.isEmpty())
```

Why would that *not* throw an exception? Try:

```
if (readjsonString == null || readJsonString.isEmpty())
{
    ...
}
```

You should definitely *not* be catching `NullPointerException` here.

Comment: noo not that part, I know I'm getting null pointerexception there, im asking about the line `readBackInfo = gson.fromJson(readjsonString, fileInfoType);`

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `readjsonString` to `null`, then calling the method `isEmpty()` on it. This is what's throwing the `NullPointerException`. Note that `null` is not the same as the empty string `""`.

If you want to `readjsonString` to start out empty, use `String readjsonString = "";`

Otherwise you should check for `null` instead, using `if (readjsonString == null)`

I'm not sure why you are catching `NullPointerException` the way you are - this exception should never be caught as it always indicates a bug.

**EDIT:** I think there might be a flaw in your logic that's building `readjsonString`. Try the following:

```
String readjsonString = "";

...

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if(!readjsonString.isEmpty()){
      readjsonString += "\n"; //append newline if it isn't the first line
   }
   readjsonString += strLine; //append line
}
```

Or with [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder readjsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

...

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if(readjsonStringBuilder.length() > 0){
      readjsonStringBuilder.append("\n");
   }
   readjsonStringBuilder.append(strLine);
}
String readjsonString = readjsonStringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: noo not that part, I know I'm getting null pointerexception there, im asking about the line `readBackInfo = gson.fromJson(readjsonString, fileInfoType);`

Comment: @Leanne - But why are you catching NPE in the loop? Why not solve the first NPE - it probably has to do with the second one since your code is just trying to eat it and keep going.

Comment: Yep i jusst fixed it , but still getting the exception from readBackInfo = gson.fromJson(readjsonString, fileInfoType);, i will edit my code